# How we can access the same cache between two war files?

Tags: java, spring, redis

I am using `@Cacheable` of `Spring` annotation to cache the data and `Redis` as the cache manager.

I created the cache with name `xyx` on one war, now I want to access/update/delete the same cache on another war.

Below is the code I have used to create the cache manager

```
@Bean
  public JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
    JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();

    // Defaults
    redisConnectionFactory.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
    redisConnectionFactory.setPort(6379);
    return redisConnectionFactory;
  }

Bean
  public RedisTemplate<String,Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory cf) {
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, Object>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(cf);
    return redisTemplate;
  }

@Primary
  @Bean(name = "cManager")
  public CacheManager cacheManager(RedisTemplate redisTemplate) {
    RedisCacheManager cm= new RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate);
    return cm;
  }
```

Below is the method to cache the data in war 1

```
@Cacheable(value = "xyz"  , cacheManager = "cManager")
public Map<String, Map<String, List<DTO>>> cachingData()
        throws CustomException {
    //logic
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as both web applications are connecting to the same Redis instance, and using the same cacheName and cache key, this should work transparently, as if it was in the same war.

Example annotation

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "myCache", key = "'myKey'")
public String myCacheableMethod(){
    return "some value";
}
```

Comment: Here we have created the cache with name 'myCache' and key 'myKey'. My query is  how we can access this same cache in another war?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The same code should work to access this same cache in another war as well. No change is code is required.

Comment: I have added the code in question. In war2 I use the same code to create cachemanager now i got the empty response when i try to getCacheNames() from cachemanager of war2